# Solution Improvement

Tags: database

I need to improve the process of saving web data into a database.
Current process:

1. Web data downloaded to a file
2. file uploaded to an online repository
3. distribution list emailed with access credentials
4. user in another institution receives access credentials and saves the file onto a shared network drive
5. user emails data processing team to make them aware the file is now in the usual location for data ingest
6. Data team executes ETL process to ingest data into a SQL DB

Comment: this is borderline a software solution, not an open data solution. if you could elaborate on what an improvement is, aka, your goals, as well as more detail in general, perhaps we can help.